# One month restiction for application free use

Tags: android, date

**Requirement:**
In my application I want to allow user to free use all features for one month from the day of application's first run. For this I have store first run date in application database and compare first run date with current date every time when application launch.

**Implementation:**
For getting current date we have several function like `Calendar.getInstance();` `Date date=new Date();` these function will return the date\datetime of the standard "wall" clock (time and date). According to [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29) `Which can be set by the user or the phone network.`

**The Problem:**
Every thing seems to be work fine but what if user change date from `Setting` and set it to past date. For example user have first run application on 7 June 2013 so after 6 July 2013 application must show that he have to purchase subscription, but if user change date of device back to 30 June etc. then the restriction will not work. 
So is there any why to implement it correctly? 
Is there any why to get actual time of device that is not be editable by user?

**Edit:**
Application can work offline, so user can turn off internet connectivity.

Comment: @Keyser Thanks for you time. Can you please tell me how to do it? any tutorial, link?

Comment: Nope sorry, I've got nothing.

Comment: How about storing the date and time the app was accessed in the shared prefs. Then if the month trial has expired, get the current devices date and time and if this date and time is in the past to what is in the shared prefs then do something like show an error to show that they have to buy the subscription

Comment: @Boardy His problem is that people can change the devices date.

Comment: yea but the user is likely not going to do it until the trial has expired at which time the correct date and time of when the app was used will be in shared prefs. if the user then changes the date to be in the past, the app can check the devices current time, compare with what was in shared prefs and if the device date is now in the past to what was in shared prefs, the user is trying to trick the app into remaining free so an error can be shown

Comment: If the devices date and time is in the past to what is in the shared prefs then do not update the shared pref, if the device date is ahead of the shared prefs then shared prefs can be updated

Comment: Is an option to not care? If the user is willing to live with a wrong date to save a <currency>, then this is not the user that will buy your app in any case.

Comment: What if I set the clock to some date in the future the first time I run the app? What if I just delete the prefs for the app or reinstall it? This is not an easy thing to get right...

Comment: @haraldK using keychain will help to store data

Comment: @haraldK, ah sorry, to much work for this wednesday, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html
but api level 16
without serverside it's really hard to do task with such open platform as android.

Answer (score 1):

How about storing two dates - the date the app was first used and the date it was last used. 30 minus the difference between the two dates will give you the number of days remaining and if the current date is earlier than the last used date you know that they have changed the date back.

Just an idea - not tried it but in theory it should work.

Comment: What if user change date before starting the app like first run date is 9 June 2013 and user always set it's date to 11 June 2013 ?

Comment: I guess if you tell the user how you are doing the date checking then sure, they will probably be able to find a way around it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Store the first day it was used and the last day it was used, and listen to the ACTION_TIME_CHANGED intent. Also, try using an AlarmManager.

Or if you have network, store it in a database off the phone.

But you probably need to ask yourself if someone really would change the date of their phone just to use your app. It would seriously mess up a lot of things for them: alarms, calenders, syncing to other services and so on. I don't think it is a problem in reality.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a possibility, you could use a one-shot GPS request to get a time value.  The user can't change the GPS time that it receives.  Adding the permission is a pain if you don't need it, but this would prevent bad behavior caused by the user mucking with the date/time.

Comment: I like this idea for getting a "safe" time value, although maybe not very user-friendly. ;-) Now, how to store the value and at the same time out of reach for the user?

Answer (score 0):

```
Event(APP_INSTALL) -> storeOnServer(INSTALL_TIME_KEY,getTimeFromServer());

Event(APP_LAUNCH) -> IF(getTimeFromServer -getStoredTime(INSTALL_TIME_KEY) >30)
  -> showTrialPeriodEndedAlert()
  -> quitApp();
```